# What hardware acceleration is supported by Google's ML Kit?

Tags: opencl, google-mlkit

I would appreciate clarity around hardware acceleration supported for ML Kit. Some applications make an explicit mention that models are run on CPU, implying that there can be other modes of acceleration. Using GPU via something like OpenCL seems like a natural way of doing so.

I wish to know if Google is capable and willing of mastering OpenCL for Machine Learning applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, ML Kit features are all running in CPU to be compatible with all devices. We are adding GPU / NNAPI support for features, and will update them in future releases.

Comment: That is nice! Would you kindly comment on role of OpenCL in planned implementation? Any notion on which future releases to look forward to, when?